# Adding Listeners to various UI elements in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, listener

While trying to implement an MVC architecture into a small little school project (and mostly failing) I am having a hard time with the data flow from UI -> controller -> model.

My UI is generally just a single JFrame with a JTabbedPane three tabs holding a JTable and a JPanel (for buttons) respectively.
One of those buttons is supposed to open a Dialog (Custom class extended from JFrame, not registered in UI class)

The user puts info into some fields in this dialog and the info should be communicated to the controller.

How do I properly register Listeners on UI elements that return input with the controller?

In the UI class, I can do it directly but the Dialog object is unknown to the controller.

My expected behavior:

- Controller defines an inner class Some_Listener
- registers Some_Listener with UI element X via public methods
- firing the ActionPerformed() collects the form input and returns it to the Collector

My example code below:

```
public class Controller {
    private UI view;
    private DataManager model;

    public Controller() {
        this.view = new UI();
        this.model = new DataManager(this);
        addListener();
    }

    public void showView() {
        this.view.setVisible(true);
    }

    public UI get_view() {
        return view;
    }

    private void addListener() {
        view.setNewElement1Listener(new NewElement1Listener());
        view.setNewElement2Listener(new NewElement2Listener());
        view.setDeleteElementListener(new DeleteElementListener());
    }

    class NewElement1Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new AddNewElementDialog("key1", view);
        }
    }

    class NewElement2Listener implements ActionListener {
         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new AddNewElementDialog("key2", view);
        }
    }

    class DeleteElementListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Implement listener
        }
    }

    class DialogApproveListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (key) {
            case key1:
                //use DialogInfo here
                break;
            case key2:
                //use DialogIngfo here too
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class AddNewElementDialog extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6744571L;
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    private JTextField tfNewElementName;
    private JFormattedTextField tfNewElementAdress;
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private JButton btnOk;
    private JButton btnCancel;
    private String key;

    public AddNewElementDialog(String key, Component mainWindow) {
        super();
        setTitle("New " + key);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        setResizable(false);
        this.key = key;
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{10, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = 
            new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = 
            new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        //ignore these; just for margins
        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_separator = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_separator.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_separator.gridx = 0;
        gbc_separator.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(separator, gbc_separator);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblName = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        gbc_lblName.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblName.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblName, gbc_lblName);

        JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Adress:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblAdress = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblAdress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblAdress.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        gbc_lblAdress.gridx = 2;
        gbc_lblAdress.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblAdress, gbc_lblAdress);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_separator_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_separator_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_separator_1.gridx = 5;
        gbc_separator_1.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(separator_1, gbc_separator_1);

        fNewElementName = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfNewElementName = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfNewElementName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfNewElementName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_tfNewElementName.gridx = 1;
        gbc_tfNewElementName.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(tfNewElementName, gbc_tfNewElementName);
        tfNewElementName.setColumns(10);

        tfNewElementAdress = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tfNewElementAdress = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tfNewElementAdress.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_tfNewElementAdress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_tfNewElementAdress.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_tfNewElementAdress.gridx = 2;
        gbc_tfNewElementAdress.gridy = 1;
        tfNewElementAdress.setColumns(10);
        contentPane.add(tfNewElementAdress, gbc_tfNewElementAdress);

        btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(e -> closeDialog());
        btnPanel.add(btnOk, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        btnPanel.add(btnCancel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_panel.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_panel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 2;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(btnPanel, gbc_panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(mainWindow);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void closeDialog(){
        this.dispose();
    }
    public String getNewElementName() {
        return tfNewElementName.getText();
    }

    public String getNewElementAddress() {
        return tfNewElementAdress.getText();
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void setDialogApproveListener(ActionListener l) {
         this.btnOk.addActionListener(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what error are you getting ? what is your question ?

Comment: I don't get any errors. I just don't know how to access the fields of AddNewElementDialog. I want to send all the inputs of the form after the Ok button is pressed to the controller.